# Springboot in gcp cloud run does not subscribe pubsub after some time

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform

We are using `PubSubInboundChannelAdapter` to pull messages from an subscriber using springboot. It works well when trying in cloud shell. It works fine after deploying code to cloud run first time but then it does not poll often and once all messages are read, the channel adapter closes and after that it does not read messages.
I tried using this doc https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gcp/current/reference/html/#inbound-channel-adapter-using-pubsub-streaming-pull

Comment: Can you post some sample code snippet of how you create message channel and receiving message? Also, check the Google doc of using `PubSubInBoundChannelAdapter` https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring#receiving-messages-using-channel-adapters

Comment: Hej i was trying the application using this example https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/spring